# Scaling option while taking picture with camera

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to give scale in and scale out option while taking picture from camera in my new application. Take for example google maps. We can zoom in and out with touch events. Similar should be image scaling. Or there might be a slider which can control scaling of image. But all of this is to be done at the time of taking picture from camera. How to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean scale in/out? You should give a lot more details if you want a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `UIImagePickerController`, you can set

```
ImagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
```

to get a native "move and scale" option after capturing the image.
check this out from documentation:

[image]

hope this will help..

Comment: Thanks. I am able to scale with back camera, but not with front camera.

Comment: Also, not setting this bool does not change anything.

Comment: setting this bool does affect for me. I'm not sure why it is not affecting your implementation.

Comment: In what way does it affect the implementation. Please tell me.

Comment: i ment that on allowsEditing=YES; i get a move & scale screen after capturing an image from within the app.

Comment: Thanks, yes it does work. But I am not able to scale in. I am only able to scale out. How to scale in?

Comment: Front camera in iPhone/iPad is VGA. Therefore they do not provide zooming facility as the resolution quality will be very poor. But you can achieve this feature by using AVFoundation (media capture) which will provide you a preview layer of camera which you can scale as per your need . But in this case you will have to design your own controls which you have in UIImagePickerController. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2

Comment: if you are looking to scale down, you need to take the image into the application then you have to use scrollview for the same.